# Fast way to scrape html tags from a collection of web pages in python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, xmlstarlet

I am trying to retrieve the content from a .gz file that contains a collection of html documents, it's a file from the GOV2 collection. Each pages is separated by the  tag, and each  tag contains several meta informations, among them  the id of the document and  (or ), its content.
Here is an exemple of such a file:

```html
<doc>
<docno>GX000-xx-xxxxxxx</docno>
<dochdr>
<!-- no relevant meta info -->
</dochdr>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 3.0//EN">

<html>
<!-- the content I want to extract -->
</html>
</doc>
<doc>
<docno>GX000-xx-xxxxxxy</docno>
<dochdr>
<!-- no relevant meta info -->
</dochdr>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 3.0//EN">

<html>
<!-- another content I want to extract -->
</html>
</doc>
```

I need to have a list containing each `docno` and each content of html tags separately.

Here is what I've done using BeautifulSoup:

```py
doc_file = 'xx.gz'
f = gzip.open(data_dir + doc_file)
doc_string = f.read()
f.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(doc_string, "html.parser")
doc_list = soup.select('DOC')

doc_no = []
doc_content = []
for doc in doc_list:
    doc_no.append(doc.find('docno').get_text())
    doc_raw = doc.find('html')
    if doc_raw is None: #It's possible a doc has no html tag
        doc_content.append('<null/>')
    else:
        doc_content.append(re.sub(r'(\n\s*)+\n+', '\n', doc.find('html').get_text()))
```

This works, but html.parser is a very slow parser (about 4 min per file, but I have several thousands to scrape from...). Thankfully, it's almost instant using another parser like `lxml`. However such a parser, for whatever reason, removes the `<html>` tags. I've tried an alternate way where I replaced these tags in doc_string (using `doc_string=doc_string.replace(b'<html>', b'<2html>'`) before calling BeautifulSoup but:

- the process is very slow
- for whatever reason the `<` are transformed into `&lt;`, to unescape it I found no easier way than decoding `doc_string`, unescape it, then re-encode it which is ridiculous time-wise. Even replacing directly `b'html'` per `b'2html'` seems to escape the `<` and `>`

Do you have a faster way to do such a task ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Great first Q! Please keep posting. Can't help with BS, but for this case, the *nix toolbox can help. Universally frowned upon to edit HTML with `sed`/`awk`, but if your data is really as regular as your example, try `sed -n '/[<]docno/p;/^[<]html[>]$/,/^[<][/]html[>]$/p' sample.html`. Otherwise, it seems like your best effort is to see if you can "fix" you `lxml` solution. Add a tag for that (note the low follower count for IR). Or tag for [xmlstarlet] or other `xml` aware tools. Good luck!

Comment: (If you have leading or trailing whitespace on the target lines, remove `^` and/or `$` chars as needed)

Comment: Thank you for your message! However using ``sed`` would mean that I need to convert each file from byte to string, process it via sed and then convert it back to byte for BS which I guess is very slow (same as unescaping), besides, the files are indeed badly formatted (many </html> missings) so I can't really using it... But thank you for the suggestions and your support ! I edited tags

Comment: OK, too bad about the missing `</html>`s, because you could do `gunzip file.gz | sed '....' | gzip > fixedfile.gz` which would be about the fastest solution (or skip the trailing `gzip` and just use `...>fixedfile`). Also note that `lxml` has even fewer followers than IR. Hopefully the python and BS tags will get the help you need. Consider changing that last tag to `xmlstartlet`, as I know it has more followers than `lxml`. Of course if it's not available in you environment, then stick with your current tags. Good luck.

Comment: 4 min per file using `html.parser` is _A LOT_. How big are the files? Maybe this is the case for using `multiprocessing` module.

Comment: Files are big indeed, about 17MB when uncompressed (down to  3.6MB in .gz). My processor is kinda old though but that's everything I have.

Comment: You dont really need a soup, do you?  Are you really using soup for some html processing/parsing we’re not seeing or are you **only** finding your boundaries in fully simple 1tag/1line files?   I agree w shellter then - on massive non html files, I ran `grep` via subprocess to find my equivalent of your docno and dochdr, *then* once I knew bounds, I dropped to python at those known lines and worked on chunks.  Massive speed boost. 2GB file in 5 minutes but that includes prepping sql and inserting into a db, and much more complicated Python grep-parsing than you within the chunks.

Comment: I’d work on `<doc>` lines, then at each boundary, walk back to find non-doc tags rather than `</html>` on previous html.  Then straight  `<html>` to find next html start.  only real requirement here is doc/html tags each are on 1 separate line *without html type in-line nesting on **those** tags*. Actual html content can be nested.

Comment: I finally posted a workaround as an answer. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in my post, I thought converting the document to string, then replacing `html` tags and then re-encode the string to bytes would be too long. Turns out I was wrong.

The strategy I used after figuring this out is to replace EVERY `html` occurence (not only tags) by another, unique word (like here in the following with `htmltag`). Then once I **scraped** the content of a `htmltag`, I replaced each remaining occurence of `htmltag` back to `html`. That way the content is not altered at all.

```html
f = gzip.open(data_dir + doc_file)
doc_string = f.read()
f.close()

doc_string_str = doc_string.decode(errors='ignore')
doc_string_str = doc_string_str.replace('html', 'htmltag')
doc_string = doc_string_str.encode()

soup = BeautifulSoup(doc_string, "lxml")
doc_list = soup.select('DOC')

doc_no = []
doc_content = []
for doc in doc_list:
    doc_no.append(doc.find('docno').get_text())
    doc_raw = doc.find('htmltag')
    if doc_raw is None: #It's possible a doc has no html tag
        doc_content.append('<null/>')
    else:
        doc_content.append(re.sub(r'(\n\s*)+\n+', '\n', doc.find('htmltag').get_text()).replace('htmltag', 'html'))
```

Thank you for @shellter and @JL_Peyret for the help, I basically followed what you told me but directly in Python. It know takes about 15 seconds per documents.

Comment: Awesome result! I couldn't believe those 4 minute times, 15 secs sounds more like it. However, If this is super critical stuff to your career, you might want to spend some of that saved time confirming you're getting accurate results ;-) !  Be sure to accept  your own answer after ~48 hrs to gain valuable reputation points!